# Elementary proof for $ x^x \geq \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2} x + x^{\frac{1}{2}} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, inequality

For all positive reals prove that $ x^x \geq \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2} x + x^{\frac{1}{2}} $

I used Bernoulli's inequality for $x \geq 1$ . $(1+x-1)^x \geq 1+x(x-1)$. We need to prove $ x(x-1)+ 1 \geq \frac{1}{2} x^2-\frac{1}{2}x + x^{\frac{1}{2}} $ which is true for $x \geq 1$. Because by $ x=t^2 $ we get $ \frac{1}{2}(t - 1)^2 (t^2 + 2 t + 2) \geq 0 $. Bernoulli's inequality doesn't help for $ 0 < x < 1 $.

Comment: We have that for $0<x\le \frac12 $ $$x^x  + \frac{1}{2} x\geq x^{\frac{1}{2}}  +\frac{1}{2}x^2$$ since $x^x  \geq x^{\frac{1}{2}}  $ and $\frac{1}{2} x\geq \frac{1}{2}x^2$ so only the case  $\frac12 <x\le1 $ remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 < x  < 1$: By Bernoulli inequality, we have
$$x^x = \frac{x}{x^{1 - x}}
\ge \frac{x}{1 + (x - 1)(1 - x)} = \frac{1}{2- x}.$$

Also, by AM-GM, we have $x^{1/2} \le \frac{x + 1}{2}$. It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{2 - x} \ge \frac12x^2 - \frac12 x + \frac{x+1}{2}$$
or
$$\frac{x(x-1)^2}{2(2 - x)}\ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{x^2+1}{2}\geq\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+\sqrt{x}$$ it's just $$(\sqrt{x}-1)^2\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that $$x^x\geq\frac{x^2+1}{2}$$ or $f(x)\geq0,$ where $$f(x)=x\ln{x}-\ln(x^2+1)+\ln2.$$
Now, $$f'(x)=\ln{x}+1-\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$$ and $$f''(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2(x^2+1-2x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x+1}{x(x^2+1)^2}>0,$$
which says that $f'$ increases and since $f'(1)=0,$ we obtain $$f(x)\geq f(1)=0,$$ which ends the proof.